# onResize() reloads my webpage causing onResize() to be called again on load again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a webpage where onResize calls a method which reloads the page by submiting a form which comes back to the same page.

This webpage is very big and something in it resizes the page or something like that causing the onResize event o be called again.

What would be the solution to stopping this infinite loop?

I can't find what is causing the onResize event to be called and even if I did then I don't want to change anything that is working already.

Is there anything I can add to my on resize method to stop it from going into an inifite loop

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     refreshMainView(); // submits form which redirects back to the same page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(**Edit:** Striking out in response to user521180's comment.)<s>Put your listener inside a `document.ready` function:</s>

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        refreshMainView(); // submits form which redirects back to the same page
    });
});
```

It sounds like your page is listening for the `resize` event while it is still adding DOM elements (and thus still calculating the size of the page).

If you already have a `document.ready` function, tTry unbinding the `resize` event in an `onbeforeunload` function and then rebinding it after the page refreshes:

```
$.unload(function () {
    $(window).unbind('resize');
});
```

Comment: the page might still be creating (and thus resizing) after dom ready, I yould try window.load

    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).unbind('resize');
    });

Comment: it still not working. unbind doesnt seem to have any effects on it. I have tired it on unload and onload

Comment: @user521180, I think there may be something in your `refreshMainView()` function causing problems.  Can you post the code for that, please?  Or create a fiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind it at first time you invoked it:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     refreshMainView(); // submits form which redirects back to the same page

     // now unbind it
     $(window).unbind('resize');
});
```